# Graph planarity and solvability by radicals

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, soft-question, planar-graphs

Every graph with four or less vertices is planar. Every polynomial with degree four or less is solvable by radicals.

There are nonplanar graphs with five and more vertices. There are polynomials with degree five and more which are not solvable by radicals.

Could there be a way to assign a group/polynomial to any graph such that the graph is planar if and only if the group/polynomial is solvable (by radicals) or nilpotent or some other property?

I don't think the polynomial $$P_G(x)=\prod_{v\text{ vertex}}(x-\text{ number of vertices adjacent to }v)$$
works but who knows, maybe somehing similar or making permutations of vertices with the alternatig groups in some way ($A_n$ not solvable for $n\ge 5$)

If this coincidence is only a coincidence, can someone provide an argument as to why we don't expect any connection of this nature?

Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid you are tripping over the Big Law of Small Numbers.

Comment: There is **one** graph with five vertices that is not planar. There are multiple polynomial of degree five that are not solvable by radicals.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen could be. Also wouldn't know it if i don't ask. I'll edit the quesiton

Comment: Graph theory and Galois theory are connected via dessins d'enfants, but no such correspondence exists (planar iff solvable) within the scope of that theory.